# Can someone tell me what are the mistakes in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 4
y = 5
a = 3(x+y)
```

I want to know the mistakes in this code. I know I am a newbie but can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried running it? What error message do you get?

Comment: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: As others are starting to point out, this is because you are trying to call 3() as a function.

Comment: @Coolorte: Please accept the answer which helped you resolve the issue for other taking this question as reference in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 3(x+y)
```

3 is not a function, and here you are trying to call it like one.

I assume you intend multiplication.  Try:

```
a = 3 * (x + y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the *syntax*. You are communication with the Python interpreter in the language it doesn't know (*like communicating to aliens in English ;)*).

When you do `3()`, python thinks you are making the call to function due to the presence of `()`. Hence you will get error as:

```
>>> 3()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

In case you want to multiply `(x+y)` with `3` and store it in `a`, your syntax should be:

```
a = 3 * (x+y)
```

Read a tutorial on [Python's Arithmetic Operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/arithmetic_operators_example.htm) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

NO operator is assumed to be present . It must be written explicitly. In the following example, the multiplication operator after b must be explicitly written. It make the code workable.

```
a = c.d.b(xy)     // usual arithmetic statement.
a = c*d*b*(x*y)   // python correct arithmetic statement.
```

I think this is also happened with you. try to avoid such mistakes.becuase you can not assume any operator to be present in any operation of any programming language.
Keep in mind when you are trying to do any operation.

your given code:

```
a = 3(x+y)
```

your correct code is :

```
a = 3 * (x + y)
```